# Сравнивание значений

Tags: php, mysql

```
Здравствуйте! Есть две таблицы. 
 1. job - работа
 2. myjob - выполненная работа
Ячейки в таблице 'job': id | category | name | stage
id - номер работы; category - категория; name - название работы; stage - макс. стадия работы, допустим запись : 1 | auto | монтажник | 5.
Ячейки в таблице 'myjob': id | id_j | user | stage | repley
id - номер записи; id_j - номер работы; user - пользователь который её выполняет | stage на какой стадии; repley - какой раз выполняет работу. допусти запись: 2 | 1 | sergey | 2 | 1. Отсюда следует, что некий Сергей выполняет работу 'Монтажник', находиться на 2-ой стадии, выполняет работу первый раз. Встал вопрос: Сергей выполняет две разные работы, первая монтажник, вторая слесарь, все две работы он выполняет первый раз, первая стадия
2/6 (2-ая из 6-и возможных), вторая 4/6 (4-ая из 6-и возможных), суть такова : Сергей выполнив обе работы ( под выполнил подразумевается макс. стадия из макс. стадии (6/6)) должен перейти на след. круг выполнения, при этом должен сброситься счётчик стадий ( stege) . Например : 
Было 2 | 1 | Сергей | 6 | 1
3 | 2 | Сергей | 6  | 1
Стало: 2| 1 | Сергей | 1 | 2
3 | 2 | Сергей | 1 | 2. Не могу понять как реализовать, подскажите пожалуйста реализацию, код я сам напишу.
```

Comment: В дополнение: пользователь сможет перейти на след. круг только тогда, когда все его работы будут на макс. стадии

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update myjob, job
set 
myjob.stage = MOD(myjob.stage,job.stage)+1,
myjob.repley = myjob.repley+floor(myjob.stage/job.stage)
where 
  job.id = myjob.id_j
  and myjob.user = 'Сергей';
```

Не сказал бы что структура у вас удобная... Раз круги у вас в явном виде зависят от количества выполненных стадий, то и считать их можно по стадиям делением на job.stage.

Comment: Спасибо, проблема решена.